# How to loop on a `hold` in CSML?

Tags: design-patterns, chatbot

I am writing a program in CSML and I want the chatbot to perform some data validation, so basically if an email or a phone number is not valid, it'd ask the question again but since we can't place a `hold` in a loop and break our of it when the data is valid, I don't quite understand how to go about that, here is the piece of code below:

```cpp
start:
    say "Hi, let sign you up!"
    goto form
    
form:
    say "What's your name?"
    hold
    remember name = event
    say "What's your email address?"
    hold
    if (!event.contains_regex("^.+@.+\..+$")) {
         say "Please enter a real email address"
         // How do I get into a loop here  to ask the question again?
    }
    remember email = event
    say "What's your phone number?"
    hold
    if (!event.contains_regex("^[+]*[(]{0,1}[0-9]{1,4}[)]{0,1}[-\s\./0-9]*$")) {
         say "Please enter a real phone number (+(123) - 456-78-90)"
         // Same problem here?
    }
    remember name = event
    // the program continues
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to break your `form` step into multiple steps. For instance:

```
form:
    say "What's your name?"
    hold
    remember name = event
    goto askEmail

askEmail:
    say "What's your email address?"
    hold
    if (!event.contains_regex("^.+@.+\..+$")) {
        say "Please enter a real email address!"
        // this will loop back to the beginning
        // of that step and ask the question again
        goto askEmail
    }
    remember email = event
    goto askPhone

askPhone:
    say "What's your phone number?"
    hold
    if (!event.contains_regex("^[+]*[(]{0,1}[0-9]{1,4}[)]{0,1}[-\s\./0-9]*$")) {
        say "Please enter a real phone number (+(123) - 456-78-90)"
        goto askPhone
    }
    remember name = event
    // the program continues
```

Steps are basically natural "loop breaking points". You can always decide to go back to a previous step or continue to a next section. All the program knows is that you want it to go somewhere if something happens, but it does not care if it's before or after where you are.

By splitting up your code in smaller bits it just makes it easier to manage!